# Centralizar o formulário ao centro com css

Tags: css

Estou com um problema para centralizar o meu formulário no centro em formato desktop.

Ele só fica centralizado no formato celular, alguém poderia me ajudar.

```
input {
    
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;  
    width: 190%;
    padding: 0 1.5rem;
    height: 4rem;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    border: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
    background: #e7e9ee;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1rem;

button {
        width: 190%;
        padding: 0 1.5rem;
        height: 4rem;
        background: rgb(22,19,209);
        color: #FFF;
        border-radius: 0.25rem;
        border: 0;
        font-size: 1rem;
        margin-top: 1.5rem;
        font-weight: 600;
        transition: filter 0.2s;
        cursor: pointer;
        &:hover {
        filter: brightness(0.9);
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Por favor explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um [exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois não está perceptível a sua pergunta. [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Uma opção é colocar seu formulário em uma div e faz o alinhamento dessa div no centro. Após isso, você define o formulário com 100% de largura da div pai:

```
<div class="section-contato">
    <form class="form-contato" action="">
        <!-- conteúdo do seu form -->
    </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.section-contato {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

form {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Você pode envolver o seu formulário em uma div com align-items: stretch; para esticar o conteúdo ao máximo, dessa forma pode remover o width do input e do button;

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 50px;
}

input {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
  height: 4rem;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  border: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
  background: #e7e9ee;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

button {
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
  height: 4rem;
  background: rgb(22,19,209);
  color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  transition: filter 0.2s;
  cursor: pointer;
  &:hover {
    filter: brightness(0.9);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="Some text">
  <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
</div>
```